# Neatly displaying grouped/multiindex Pandas dataframes in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have just started off using Streamlit, which in many ways is a really neat way of quickly analyse and view data in different ways, and then share it with colleagues.

Displaying dataframes in Streamlit works fine - but gets very tedious when one wants to have specific formatting etc. It seems to get even worse when using grouped or MultiIndex dataframes.

Does anyone know if there is a neat way of formatting, and displaying, either grouped or MultiIndex dataframes using Streamlit?

Comment: What about displaying df.reset_index() ?

Comment: Hi @gussilago -- we have [an extremely active community Streamlit forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/) where your question is far more likely to get a richer response.  StackOverflow is great for questions that have definitive answers; our forum works much better when you need back-and-forth and creativity.     https://discuss.streamlit.io/